# How to read from a file if one is given in the command line c++

Tags: c++

How should I read from a file if there is one given as a command line argument, if not I would like to read from std::cin. I tried to solve this with pointers to istrem, but is there a better way.

Comment: 1) "_I tried to solve this with pointers to istrem_" Why would you need to use pointers to `std::ifstream`? 2) Please show [mcve] with an actual question. SO is **not** code writing service.

Comment: @DevSolar Does not look like a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

You probably tried to use a pointer to `istream` to have it point to either an `std::fstream` instance or to `std::cin` depending on the command line parameters.

It would be better as a reference:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::fstream fin;

    if (argc > 1)
        fin.open(argv[1]);

    std::istream &in = fin.is_open() ? fin : std::cin;

    // ... continue using `in`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ifstream` derives from `istream`. So if a file is given on the command line then you open the file and use the resulting ifstream as istream. Otherwise you use std::cin.

Answer (score -2):

Check this : [How do you open a file in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880/how-do-you-open-a-file-in-c)

With the exception that path_to_file is an input coming from std::cin or command line argument.

Comment: If the answer to the question, is present in another SO question, one should flag as duplicate, **not** to post his own answer linking to another one..